# MVC4 Date Picker with Default Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datepicker

I am using MVC4 with the Razor view engine. My controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View(new EmployeeIndexViewModel
    {

        ToDate = DateTime.Now

    });

}
```

My View Model is as follows:

```
public class EmployeeIndexViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

On my view I have a simple `EditorFor()` call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToDate)
```

But still get a default (masked) value in my date picker:

[image: Empty Date Picker]

**QUESTION:**

How can I get today's date (from controller) to display here instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My problem was not a jQuery or MVC4 problem as I had initially thought. It has to do with how the HTML5 compatible browser displays the date picker. I was passing the date to the view in the incorrect format.

I modified my ViewModel to this and now the date populates correctly:

```
public class EmployeeIndexViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Correctly displaying date time]

Comment: One thing I would point out for this is that the DataFormatString format is different from what is actually displayed. If you were to use DataFormatString of MM/dd/yyyy then it would not work. It seems you have to use yyyy-MM-dd regardless of how your date is actually formatted.

Comment: You passed `yyyy-MM-dd` in the attribute, but I see in your photo `MM/dd/yyyy`. What is happening? I am asking because I want to change that order in my view but I have the same problem I see in your picture.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this from jQuery level:

```
   $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", yourDate);
```

For example, if you want to set the today's date:

```
   $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
```

You can also try adding the `DisplayFormat` attribute in your view model class to make sure that the date picker will interpret your data format correctly:

```
public class EmployeeIndexViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would you reflect this change in the .cshtml file? Would you remove the `.EditorFor()` call and statically insert a Text Box?

Comment: Try firstly with adding the attribute I suggested, it seems to be the easiest solution

Comment: I did that, Date Picker still displays as it does in the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Change your editor for to : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToDate, new { id = "toDate"}); And then   $( "#toDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());

Comment: The problem is not the jQuery, its the `.EditorFor()` call adding `type='date'` attribute to the HTML attribute.

Comment: This answer would have worked, if not for `.EditorFor()` adding the `type='date'` attribute to the input element.

Answer (score 1):

U can set the Input or Input with type="date" (datetimepicker) using JQuery.

In Razor view

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartedDate, new { @id = "mydate", @type = "date", @class = "form-control" })

Here is the JS code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateNewFormat, onlyDate, today = new Date();

        dateNewFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-';
        if (today.getMonth().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }

        onlyDate = today.getDate();
        if (onlyDate.toString().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += "-" + onlyDate;
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '-0' + onlyDate;
        }

        $('#mydate').val(dateNewFormat);
    });
```